# redirect user if not logged in in html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, redirect, logging

I want to redirect not logged user to Login.html  if they are not logged in and try to browse my Startpage. I am using cookies and used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        if(Cookies.get('user') == undefined) {
         window.location.replace("http://localhost/login.html");
         //window.location.href = "http://localhost/login.html";
         //$(location).attr('href', 'http://localhost/login.html');
        }
    });
```

The Problem is that the browser shows for a half second the Startpage and redirect afterwards.

Is it possible not showing the Startpage at all? Or is it only possible with PHP-Sessions

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
header("location:login.html");
exit;
}
```

Comment: This is better done in PHP. If it's done in the browser, the user can override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the code in `$(document).ready()`, since that doesn't run until the page is loaded. Put it in a script block in the `<head>`, and it will run before the page is rendered.

Comment: If you need to guarantee that a non-logged-in user is redirected, I do. If it's just a convenience feature, JS is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in the  to save the user some time by stopping the page load  if not logged in

```
<script>
if (/*you are not logged in. */) {
    try {
      //stop most browsers loading
        window.stop();
    } 
    catch (e) {
      //IE stop loading content 
        document.execCommand('Stop');
    } 
    document.location.replace(/*user login page */);
}
</script>
```